# "one is ... another is ... " and "the first is ... the second is ...."

Tags: meaning, grammar, synonyms, academia

I am writing an academic paper. I use the following representations:

> However, up to now, far too little attention has been devoted to two
> problems of the state-of-the-art proof automation systems. One is ...
> Another is ...

Somebody advises me to use

> However, up to now, far too little attention has been devoted to two
> problems of the state-of-the-art proof automation systems. The first is ...
> The second problem is ...

Does the reason come from that "The first is ... The second problem is ..." is more formal, or
more clear?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One is ... Another is .../ "The first is ... The second problem is ..." are both awkward and lead to other problems: this style of enumeration/ordering should be avoided. You need a variant of *However, up to now, far too little attention has been devoted to A and B, which are problems in/for of the state-of-the-art proof automation systems." PS what is a "proof automation system"?

Comment: @Greybeard Thank you most sincerely! Your suggestions help me make more clear sentences! Before you told me, I never think about this question. A "proof automation system" is a system that is used to help people construct proofs by computer programs more easily.

Comment: *A "proof automation system" is a system that is used to help people construct proofs by computer programs more easily.* Thanks!

Comment: *… systems: (1) something, and (2) something else.* The numbers aren't required, but they aid comprehension if what follows the colon are long phrases.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for your suggestions! Could I ask one more question? In fact, I introduce each reason in a new paragraph. Could I adopt "… systems: new paragraph (1) something.  new paragraph  (2) something else."

Comment: @ZhangLiao If they are really that long, then set the list item paragraphs off in actual  list items. Everything up to the colon will be a complete (introductory) sentence.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: You'd use 'One is ...' 'The other X is' (because it's already been mentioned notionally). X is 'problem' if the first ellipsis is long, otherwise blank (and perhaps with a new paragraph). // Similarly with 'The first is ... The second X is ...'.